# How to select a python interpreter in vim

Tags: filetype-python, python

I have multiple versions of python on my ubuntu system, `python2.7` which is default one and i have installed `python3.8`. I have a python module installed in `python3.8` which is not installed in `python2.7`. so when is import that module in a python script in vim. It gives `import-error`. how do i switch between python interpreters in vim?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have a look at `:help if_pyth` and `:help python-2-and-3`

Comment: You use neovim which handles this well.